# CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android

I'm doing a manipulation in database in an `IntentService`, and in the `Activity` im showing a CustomProgressBar, but I want to show also the percentage value. So, for that I get the percentage value in the IntentService and set this value in a static method in the Activity. But the error show up:

> CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created
>   a view hierarchy can touch its views.

I dont want to do this operation in an AsyncTask becaus I don't want to block the UI, so I'm using a IntentService.

Here is how I am doing this.

**MyIntentService.java**

public class MyIntentService extends IntentService
{
    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    { 
        updateDatabase();
    }

```
public void updateDatabase()
{
    resetPercentage(cursor.getCount * 2) 
    do
    {
      // do operation for updating the database

      // here I update the view everytime a new item is inserted in DB.
      int updatedReturn = MyActivity.updatePercentageValue(percentage()); 
    }
    while(...)
}

public void resetPercentage(int elementsNum)
{
mUpdatePercentage = 0;

mMaxItems = elementsNum;
}

public int incrementPercentageCounter()
{
return ++mPercentageCounter;
}

public int percentage()
{
    int value = (mPercentageCounter/mMaxItems)*100;

return (value > 100) ? 100 : value;
}
}
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
     private TextView mMyTextView;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
     {
         super.onCreate(bundle);
         mMyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
     }

     public static int updatePercentageValue(int percentageValue)
     {
         mMyTextView.setText("" + percentageValue + " %");

         return 1;
     }
}
```

Any Idea of how can I solve this problem or do this operation using my IntentService so the UI wont be blocked.

**Obs: I want to keep using IntentService also because a lot of things is done, and I dont want to change all over again.**

Thanks!

Comment: Your activity code here seems incomplete or different from what you have. is `mMyTextView` supposed to be the same variable as `mPercentageValueTextView`? Is that supposed to be a static variable? You really should avoid using static accessors for this kind of thing. It's not a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

An AsyncTask won't block the UI. You should probably use it. The kind of thing you're trying to do is exactly what it's good for. The AsyncTask doesn't need to exist outside of your Activity, it's short-lived work (relatively), and your work needs to update this UI. An AsyncTask seems more appropriate than a Service here.

Answer (score 1):

Doing things in an async task is specifically to not block the UI thread. It even has an on progress method to do exactly what you want to do wih updating the UI. Gven that you don't want to do that, but you need to look into the running method.

Looking at this code I am somewhat confused as to how it works since you are accessing a member variable in a static method.

Comment: Is it a good idea to inside the AsyncTask I call the IntentService?

Comment: It won't hurt anything, but as the answer above stated, a service is not really what you want, you but it should work fine. After some progress you can tell Android you had some progress to report - I forget he method name, but check the documents for AsyncTask and that method then call onProgressDisplay using the UI thread so you can update the UI.

Comment: I just want to separate the control code from the view code. But it I call the IntentService in the Asynctask I'm gonna create another Thread, right?? But the IntentService stops itselft after the work is done, right??

Comment: Calling the IntentService from the AsyncTask won't help. You'll still have the same problem of figuring out how to communicate your progress from your IntentService to the AsyncTask. It's really not that hard to refactor. Take the time and do it the right way.

Comment: I created an AsyncTask in my actvity class and inside the doInBackground() method I call another method in the controller class that does all the operation, and constantly call the static method in the Activity to update the value in the screen, but the same error keeps. What can it be? Thanks!

Comment: You have to read about async task. You can't directly call the static method from the doBakground call if it changes the UI. You can push it some new data, and then read step 3 in the apu doc. You can only update the UI in the onProgressDisplay method. Read step 3 in the ani document for AsyncTask, you need to call publishProgress in the background thread. That will cause the onProgressDisplay method to be invoked by android some time later using the UI thread where it can update the UI.

Comment: Wow, things this on my tablet causes some strange typos. Anyway apu and ani both should have said api.